# htaccess to rewrite folder, add trailing slash and remove .html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-s3

I'm trying to accomplish three things:

1. Render html files from an s3 bucket on http://mywebsite[dotcom]/somefolder
2. Remove the .html extension
3. Enforce a trailing slash so that `/somefolder/file.html` ends up as
   `/somefolder/file/`

This is the closest I've gotten to achieving all of this, but every rule I try to enforce trailing slash ends up breaking things.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^somefolder/(.*)$ http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/$1 [p]
```

Is is possible to do all of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1/ [R=301,L]
```